# PHP file upload image + Canvas php resize

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload, canvas

I'm creating a file uploads script for my website and using canvas.php to scale down the image. The upload works fine but the scaling doesn't. I've never used this before so I'm hoping it's just a minor error. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$newfilename = $id;

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

$path = "../posts/$type/";

//INSERT TO TABLE
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $newfilename . "." . $extension);
    header("Location: ../dashboard.php?page=posts");
    exit();
}
else{
header("Location: ../404.php");
}
?>
<?php
if($type == "photo"){
require_once "canvas.php";
$img = new canvas("$path" . $newfilename . "." . $extension);
$img
->resize("700")
->save("$path" . $newfilename . "." . $extension);
}
?>
```

This uses canvas.php (http://canvas.daviferreira.com/)

Comment: `canvas` as in the PEAR library?

Comment: @MarcB It's canvas.php - http://canvas.daviferreira.com/